# Title and table position in a paper

Tags: tables

I am writing a seminar paper with latex, and currently working on Appendix. The problem is, that i want the title and the explanation of the table be on top of the page, but somehow LaTeX shows it other way around. Could you please help me, or tell what I am doing wrong in my code?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \begin{document}
    \onehalfspacing
    \rmfamily


    \section*{Appendix}

    ln(ABCP $Out_{t-1}$) is lagged log ABCP outstanding, and  $\Delta$ ln(ABCP       $Out_{t-1}$) is lagged log net ABCP issuance (the lagged change in log ABCP outstanding). Panel A uses the ABCP – T-bill spread as the independent variable, while Panel B uses the OIS-T-bill spread. The sample runs weekly from July 2001-June 2007. YM denotes year-month fixed effects, while WOY denotes week-of-year fixed effects. Robust standard errors are reported in parentheses, except for the specifications without fixed effects. *, **, *** denote significance at the 10\%, 5\%, and 1\% levels respectively. \\

   \begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   \multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel A: ABCP - T-Bill Spread} \\
   \hline 
   ABCP - T-Bill $Spread_{t-1} $&$0.013$***&$0.0012$*** &$0.010$*** &$0.012$***     &$0.011$**\\
   &$(0.002)$&$(0.004)$&$(0.002)$& $(0.004)$&$(0.004)$ \\
   ln(ABCP $Out_{t-1}$)&&&$0.002$&$-0.360$***&$-0.439$***\\
   &&&$(0.002)$&$(0.061)$& $(0.066)$\\
   $\Delta$ ln(ABCP $Out_{t-1}$)&&&$0.138$**&$0.007$ & $0.073$\\
   && &$(0.066)$&$(0.074)$&$(0.082)$ \\
   Constant&$-0.001$**&$-0.001$ &$-0.026$ &$4.874$*** & $5.991$***\\

   &$(0.001)$&$(0.001)$&$(0.030)$&$(0.830)$ & $(0.896)$\\

   \hline
   $R^2$&$0.164$&$0.045$ &$0.172$ &$0.243$ &$0.362$ \\
   N&$303$&$303$ &$301$ &$301$ &$301$ \\
   FE&--&$YM$ &-- &$YM$ &$YM,WOY$ \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{5}{c}{Panel B: OIS - T-Bill Spread} \\
   \hline 
    OIS - T-Bill $Spread_{t-1}$&$0.012$***&$0.009$** &$0.009$*** &$0.013$***    &$0.012$**\\
    &$(0.002)$&$(0.004)$&$(0.002)$& $(0.004)$&$(0.005)$ \\
    ln(ABCP $Out_{t-1}$)&&&$0.002$&$-0.359$***&$-0.434$***\\
     &&&$(0.002)$&$(0.068)$& $(0.071)$\\
     $\Delta$ ln(ABCP $Out_{t-1}$)&&&$0.125$**&$0.014$ & $0.091$\\
    && &$(0.069)$&$(0.083)$&$(0.086)$ \\
     Constant&$-0.001$**&$-0.000$ &$-0.022$ &$4.862$*** & $5.919$***\\

     &$(0.000)$&$(0.001)$&$(0.031)$&$(0.923)$ & $(0.969)$\\

     \hline
      $R^2$&$0.169$&$0.028$ &$0.178$ &$0.224$ &$0.358$ \\
      N&$287$&$287$ &$286$ &$286$ &$286$ \\
      FE&--&$YM$ &-- &$YM$ &$YM,WOY$ \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{ABCP Net Issuance and Spreads}\label{pred}
    \end{table}

      \end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{table}[b]` to insert the table at the bottom.

Comment: Even `\begin{table}[!h]` works.

Comment: Note that if you want the tabular placed exactly where you put it, you can just not wrap it in a `table` environment at all. A `table` is a float i.e. it tells LaTeX to figure out where to place it and move it appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! Feedback: with \begin{table}[!h] works perfect, text and table on the one page, \begin{table}[b] puts the table to the next page, don't know why... Solved and saved!